# Скорость выполнения приложения Node

Tags: node.js, асинхронность, promise, скорость

Я написал рабочий код который вытаскивает атрибуты пользователя из Active Directory. Он в двух вариантах, как promise и как async / await. Проблема в том, что на ноутбуке оба варианта выполняются за менее чем за секунду и это доступ к 7-ми лесам AD через VPN. Когда я помещаю этот код на сервер в локальную сеть (то есть уже VPN нет), это VMware VM Debian 12, два процессора и 6 GB RAM, на котором express публикует полученные данные на страницу /api/users, время выполнения кода становится 20 секунд!
Версии Node одинаковые, зависимости идентичные. Именно выполнение кода, не публикация данных express, он вообще может быть не запущен. По графикам VM, никаких проблем с ресурсами нет, ноутбук MacBook Pro mid 2015 (RAM 16 Gb, SSD500).
Для меня ситуация более чем странная, есть какие то мысли?

UPD: добавил код

```
const getBVRP = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const ad = new ActiveDirectory(conn_bvrp)
  ad.findUsers(fltLDP, function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
      reject(console.error(JSON.stringify(err.message)))
    } else if (!users || users.length == 0) {
      resolve('No users found')
    } else {
      resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users)))
    }
  })
})

const promises = [getVRP, getUTT, getBVRP, getMSK, getKVRZ, getNKS, getBVRZ]

const allUsersArr = []

const allUsers = Promise.allSettled(promises).then((results) =>
  results.forEach((data) => {
    if (data.status === 'fulfilled') {
      console.log(data.status)
      allUsersArr.push(...data.value)
    } else {
      console.log(data.status)
    }
  })
)

export const usersFromPromises = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(allUsersArr)
}
```

UPD: express

```
const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, () => {
  console.log('- https://amber.domain.com')
  console.log(`- process ID ${process.pid} port ${port}`)
  console.log('- Рабочий каталог:', process.cwd())
  // console.log('- Шаблонизатор:', app.get('view engine'))
  // console.log('- Шаблонизатор:', app.get('views'))
})

app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :remote-addr :res[content-length] - :response-time ms :date[web]'.brightBlue))

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(router)
```

UPD: routes

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import { usersFromPromises } from "../apiPromises.js";
// import { users } from '../controllers/ldapReq.js'

const router = Router()

router.get('/api/v3/users', usersFromPromises)

export default router
```

Comment: Мысль — это не проблема nodejs. Ищите проблему в настройках сети, таймаутах, доступах.

Comment: @AlexeyTen добавил код, заметил одну странность, выполнение кода всегда происходит как бы одновременно, fulfilled я получаю в обоих случаях сразу, то есть сначала ничего 19 секунд, потом за секунду приходят все 7 fulfilled ... Как будто на сервере, что то тормозит его исполнение на 20 секунд

Comment: Не вижу странности. Вы ж сами написали `allSettled` который ждёт когда завершаться все промисы. Так что для начала выясните какой из них тормозит 20 секунд.

Comment: А как это можно обработать? Где вставить что то, что покажет время выполнения promise?

Comment: В каждый промис. Хотя бы так: `promises.forEach((p,k)=>p.finally(() => console.log(k, 'finished at', Date()))`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Благодарю, теперь я могу сетевикам аргументированно указать на проблему!

Comment: Как совершенно правильно указал @AlexeyTen проблема сетевая и его код помог мне в этом разобраться